# mysql prepared statements, is this possible?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

```
function fetchbyId($tableName,$idName,$id){
        global $connection;
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, 'SELECT * FROM ? WHERE ? = ?'); 
        var_dump($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$tableName);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$idName);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$id);
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($name,$id);
        $fetchArray = array();
        while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
            $fetchArray[] = $row;
        }
        return $fetchArray;
    }
```

can i use the place holders for table names to or is this only possible for table columns?

Comment: it's not possible for the columns either. That's quite useless function which you are trying to build. It will save you from typing 3 words but will make your code WAY less readable.

Comment: make it just one general purpose function to be run like this `$data = getRow("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?", $id);`

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Unfortunately this solution (getRow) deprives him of database abstraction. Switching to XML or object storage would be a pain...

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I think you don't know what you are talking about. I've switched systems from SQL to NoSQL (e.g.: MongoDB) a lot and I know that having database abstraction really is a key factor in the switching time. If you have a properly designed system to handle such things, then yes, it can be as easy as changing drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it only accepts values (i.e.: not columns, table names, schema names and reserved words), as they will be escaped. You can do this though:

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = ?', $tableName, $idName);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$id);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Table and column names are syntax, values are data. Syntax cannot be parameterized.

The table/column name can safely be inserted into the string directly, because they come from a proven, limited set of valid table/column names (*right?*). Only user-supplied values should be parameters.

```
function fetchbyId($tableName,$idName,$id){
    global $connection;
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $idName = ?"); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$id);
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($name,$id);
    $fetchArray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
        $fetchArray[] = $row;
    }
    return $fetchArray;
}
```

Comment: "Only user-supplied values should be parameters" - you cannot be more wrong, dude

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: As opposed to "values that come from a controlled environment". Note that I did not say *"values that are not user supplied must not be parameters"*. But maybe you explain to me why I could not be more wrong and what justifies the downvote.

Comment: There are apostrophes and nulls in the "controlled environment" as well. Prepared statements **ARE** designed to make a developer **NOT** to think of the data origin. Go figure

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: No, there are not, because it's a controlled environment. Go figure. Don't expect that I am so stupid to call arbitrary free text that can contain anything including SQL syntax elements a "controlled environment". -- Okay, maybe that's not entirely self-explanatory. For me, a "controlled environment" is a strictly syntax-checked, ideally hard-coded list of elements that cannot possibly break an SQL statement. Like a list of allowable table or column names. Everything else goes into parameters.

Comment: You are answering not to yourself but to unsuspicious noob. Thousands of them. So the last correction is right one

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel. Point taken. :) See extended previous comment.